# Convert check mark in Python

Tags: python, python-module-unicodedata

I have a dataframe which has, in a certain column, a check mark (unicode: '\u2714'). I have been trying to replace it with the following coomand:

```
import unicodedata
df['Column'].str.replace(unicodedata.lookup("\u2714"), '')
```

But, i keep on reading this error: KeyError: "undefined character name '✔'".

Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Rather then replacig `unicodedata.lookup("\u2714")`, have you tried to just replace `"\u2714"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*check mark (unicode: '\u2714')*

No. This is `SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL FIVE`. `unicodedata.lookup` should be feed with Unicode name of character, not character itself. You might use `.str.replace` with Unicode characters directly, so rather than

```
import unicodedata
df['Column'].str.replace(unicodedata.lookup("\u2714"), '')
```

you might do

```
df['Column'].str.replace("\u2714", '')
```

simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['YES\u2714']})
print(df["col"].str.replace("\u2714", ''))
```

output

```
0    YES
Name: col, dtype: object
```